# Import existing Android project results in a lot "bugs" in JNI folder

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface

I have an eclipse project with native library and I need to copy this project into another machine.

I coping this project folder there and use "File->New->Android Project from Existing Code". I also using tick "Copy projects into workspace".

Then I go to jni folder and see a lot of bugs like "Unresolved inclusion: ", "Type 'JNICALL' could not be resolved", "Method 'GetStringUTFChars' could not be resolved", etc. 31 errors at all.

I trying to compile this jni library. No problem. It has compiled but I still see all bugs which I see before.
I trying to launch android application and it saying me that my project containing errors.

This problem only with a native libraries.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Project Propriets >> C/C++ General >> Paths and Symbols and Add:

```
"/home/ademar/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include"
```

you can include de x86 and mips version too:

```
"/home/ademar/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-x86/usr/include"
"/home/ademar/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-18/arch-mips/usr/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get stuck with these error messages from Eclipse, you should simply go to the "Problems" view and delete the messages. Clean build the project, and the messages will (hopefully) not appear again.

Sometimes, more radical measures are required, like opening a new workspace (simple delete project + import it back may not be enough, because some project metadata is not removed on delete).

The last resort is to go to the project properties, find the **Builders** tab, and disable the last **Scanner Configuration Builder**. Unfortunately, this will also disable "Open Declaration" and other smart source navigation features.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who runs into similar problems, I encountered this error because I'd copied C-style JNI calls into a `cpp` file. So, if that's the case for you as well, try changing

```
const char *utf8 = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filename, NULL);
```

to

```
const char *utf8 = env->GetStringUTFChars(filename, NULL);
```

Then clean/build.